# How to setup cdn in "Litespeed Cache" in wordpress plugin?

Tags: wordpress, cdn

I have problem to setuping the cdn.
how to setup the cdn with https protocol in Litespeed cache?
Are the file in

```
/wp-content
```

important to move in directory cdn?

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to the CDN setup within the plugin itself? You don't need to specifically do anything with any directories, including `/wp-content`.

Assuming you've already set up your CDN on the CDN's website, all you need to do to make it work with the LSCache plugin is to visit the **LiteSpeed Cache > Settings > CDN** tab, and configure a few options.

Most notably, you need to let LSCache know your site's original URI, the CDN URL, and the types of static files your CDN will be responsible for serving. (Your CDN should only be serving static files, as LSCache is responsible for caching the dynamic content.)

If you are using Cloudflare, you can disregard the above. There is no need to do anything special in LSCache to make it work with Cloudflare.

There are detailed CDN configuration instructions on [the LiteSpeed wiki](https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php/litespeed_wiki:cache:lscwp:configuration:cdn), if you need more information.

Comment: And how to connecting these cdn to my site?

Comment: If you setup a CDN for your domain, you may get a URL which could access to your site just same as your site URL. After you setup CDN with LSCache plugin, static files, e.g. css, images. will start serving from CDN instead of your server. You can verify it by developer browser tool.